# Screenshot of the Week #103

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest is over.

*[previous contest](//meta.arqade.com/q/16933) | [next contest](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16962/screenshot-of-the-week-104-explosions)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **103<sup>rd</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [GammaGames'](//meta.arqade.com/a/16941/28182) picture from [ooblets](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ooblets) won with 15 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](//arqade.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2023-11-20, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2023-11-27, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## No Theme

There is no theme this week, so post anything that tickles your fancy!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](//meta.arqade.com/q/15029).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](//meta.arqade.com/q/14939) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Comment: I love how last contest's winner was a late submission, but still came out the top. Let that be an encouragement to those who think they shouldn't submit an entry because it's submission period is close to an end

Comment: I also love how it looks, by the way. Makes Arqade look a lot friendlier and, well, gamey.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image]
Mario relaxing in the wooded kingdom in [super-mario-odyssey](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-mario-odyssey)

Comment: First I thought that was a big drop of water, flying in from the right, one millisecond before waking Mario up, then I thought the bird was transparent. I had to zoom in really far to see that all patterns I saw just randomly happened to lined up, it's just a regular (shiny blue) bird.

Comment: @FabianRöling I agree, the bird does appear at first glance to be semitransparent.

Comment: This is on my little brother's save file. That outfit is hideous.

Comment: It seems your little Brother will win.

Comment: I was just joking.but It is really sweat like sugar

Comment: @nobody I think you meant sweet. Chances are sweat's taste is more salty than sweet 

Comment: @User 23415  Can I use your picture as desktop background for my notebook?

Comment: @nobody Sure, I'm fine with that.

Comment: @User23415 thank you It is so relaxing exactly what I need. 

Comment: @nobody I have a better one https://i.stack.imgur.com/2U7Bw.jpg

Comment: @User23415 from relaxing no sign eek.

Comment: Oops, wrong file...

Comment: Perhaps this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hfvft.jpg

Comment: Or maybe you'll like this one? https://i.stack.imgur.com/vY8mb.jpg

Comment: The Last one is cool. Which Game please? @User23415

Comment: @nobody The graphics look like _Zelda: Breath of the Wild_ although it could also be _Zelda: Tears of the Kingdom_

Answer (score 13):

The nature of the department - [control](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/control)

[image: Control]

Answer (score 9):

Gladolius, about to swat a Cactuar for its misdeed, in [final-fantasy-15](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-15)

[image: The scene depicts Gladolius, as he raises his heavy sword using only his right hand. It looks as if he is about to use it as a flyswatter to hit the tiny little Cactuar hiding in the grass.]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMKko.jpg

Answer (score 9):

[image]

---

[deus-ex-mankind-divided](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deus-ex-mankind-divided)

Answer (score 6):

Beginning of the end in [final-fantasy-13-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-13-2) after etros's death the chaos swallowed grand pulse and cocoon.

[image: mog]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Olaf Craig riding a Tank in Trails of Cold Steel 2]

*"Drive me closer, I want to hit it with my sword"*

Sir, this is a Kiseki game

[trails-of-cold-steel-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trails-of-cold-steel-2)

Comment: Is this a Wh40k reference?

Comment: @Clockwork yep - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-hB19tHMS94&t=8s

Comment: That voice line from Dawn of War is actually referencing a Warhammer 40k meme that already existed before: https://scottthong.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/drivemecloser.jpg

Comment: Oh I remember this place and the Hippo cryptic there.

Answer (score 3):

Ratchet contemplates the Blarg Tactical Research station at Nebula G34.
[ratchet-and-clank](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ratchet-and-clank)

[image: Blarg Tactical Research station, Nebula G34]

Comment: A GOAT game series.

Answer (score 3):

Launching holy missiles in [god-of-weapons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/god-of-weapons)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: ugh]

Is it really 3am in [roblox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roblox) (Moderation Life)?