Should we encourage people to use Stack Exchange image hosting instead of a third party hosting service?
On some occasions, some users are using a third party hosting service instead of just posting the image directly by pasting into the question/answer form or clicking the image button to insert an image file (most of the time I saw some users using imgur for example).
The problem with that is the images may disappear, which may nullify the entire purpose of the post. Example: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16949/226066 (a screenshot of the week submission where a user used their own website to post and share a screenshot, but since the website went down, we no longer know what was posted, unless it was archived).
Should we encourage people to just use Stack Exchange's image posting feature when we notice the link of the image is a third party hosting service?
Granted, I know some legal questions may arise about the fact that, if the image is posted directly, it will be licensed under CC BY-SA.

There is probably a discussion on this somewhere - either on this meta, or SE Meta.  But I'd say generally yes, you would want to encourage it because it's less likely that the image will become a broken link over time. I typically edit posts to replace 3rd party hosted images with the SE image host.

We could, but the real question is how. And this whole discussion stands or falls with the method(s) used, I think. The editor clearly shows an image icon, so the more observing user will be guided towards that. And I believe the rest of the cases is rare enough to be changed through edits (I have done a lot of post-processing on images that proved too large for Imgur/i.sstatic).

@Joachim I was mostly thinking about writing a comment, since (on Meta at least) I don't have enough reputation to edit a post on Gaming Stack Exchange, although that may not make a difference for many possible reasons.

Oh, right, I thought you were talking about an automatic method, like the notification we get when we don't change an image description. Leaving a comment is always good, but I'm guessing it's mostly new users who don't take the time to inform themselves who are not using the built-in image uploader, and they are usually also the ones who don't really go and edit their own posts. But it will definitely help on occasion. Also: you do have enough reputation to edit, your edits just need to go through Review first.

@Joachim I don't know, unlike on main sites, when I attempt to edit a Meta post, I'm greeted with a scary red message that says: "Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites."

I suppose that's because Meta is more about personal input and not objective information. But you're still able to edit? And were you talking about images on Meta specifically, or in general (here and the main site)?

@Joachim A bit of both, although I must admit since I'm participating in Screenshot of the Week posts, that's where I saw a screenshot disappear because it was hosted on a personal website. And nah, on Meta, I cannot edit at all, I can just write a comment, whereas on the main site, it can enter an edit review queue.

I'm not sure how the moderators here feel about it, but if I were one, I wouldn't mind you flagging those posts and leave a custom reason saying the image host is suboptimal. Perhaps one of the mods can chime in here :)

@Joachim Yeah I did consider that too, but I felt it might be inappropriate usage of moderator flag, which is why I ended up creating this thread.

See this incident for an example of what can happen with third-party image hosts. And also this related feature request from 10 years ago.

@Joachim Users can't suggest edits on meta sites. Users need 2,000 reputation points to edit posts on meta, and Clockwork currently has only 521 rep. Related MSE post: Why can't I suggest edits on SE meta sites?

I'm trying to access the original image from the mentioned meta post using the Internet Archive, but whenever I try to view the archived page on archive.org, I get redirected to the meta post instead: https://web.archive.org/web/20240000000000*/https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16943/screenshot-of-the-week-103 Is anyone else encountering the same issue?

@galacticninja Yeah, you have to disable Javascript before clicking on the link (either by disabling it globally or using NoScript addon to specifically block archive.org). Which is strange because I've accessed some Stack Exchange snapshots in the past and it didn't happen. Sadly, it wasn't archived. But checking did allow me to realise there's a really strange bug going on: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14149/103122

@galacticninja The Wayback issue just got mentioned on Meta here. Apparently, it's because of the "unauthorized access" block that's in place on the network.

@galacticninja As a follow-up, a staff member clarified that the cause isn't related to the unauthorized access block.

Potential workarounds are suggested there as well, like disabling JavaScript, or by adding "id_ after the timestamp in a way back URL" (Makyen and Jeremy, respectively).
